# need help for array

Tags: sas

I need create some new variables `day1` `day2` `day3` etc. If `readmit=1`then do `day[i]` each `day[i]=gap` For example, the first two readmit should get `day[1]=21` `day[2]=9`. then the next `readmit=1`,  For the third readmit, the fourth readmit and the fifth `readmit=1` should get the result `day[1]=29` `day[2]=12` `day[3]=23` and so on. Hopefully, I expressed well enough. Thanks in advance.

```
 STUDYID   index     readmit    gap  
   10001      1        0                
   10001      1        0        79  
   10001      1        0        48  
   10001      1        0        39  
   10001      1        0        74  
   10001      1        0        41  
   10001      0        1        21  
   10001      0        1        9       
   10001      0        0        130 
   10001      0        0        52  
   10001      0        0        110 
   10001      1        0        80  
   10001      0        1        29  
   10001      0        1        12  
   10001      0        1        23  
   10001      1        0        57  
   10001      0        1        28  
   10001      0        1        14  
   10001      1        0        118 
   10001      0        1        5       
   10001      0        1        22  
   10001      1        0        40  
   10001      0        1        23  
   10001      0        1        24  
   10001      0        1        19
```

Comment: Use the `code` block in your editor , and arrange your data in a table please.

Comment: In addition, please strip out any columns not needed for your example.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you try to describe more clearly what you want? Also @RWill's suggestion to help make the example more clear. And finally, a good way to give people an incentive to answer your question is to go back to earlier questions and mark the best one as "accepted".

Comment: Thanks Robbie to revise for me. I leave the columns in case need it help to figure out.  Anyway, I will remove it next time.             For the question,

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below answers your question.  This requires 2 passes of the data, the first to calculate the maximum number of consecutive rows where READMIT=1, which is stored in a macro variable used to determine the array size in the second pass.

The key to solving this question is the order of the data and the use of the NOTSORTED option in the BY statement.  This enables every change in the READMIT value to be treated as a new section.

Hope this helps, although it would be good if someone could find a method that just uses a single pass of the data.

```
    data have;
    input STUDYID   index     readmit    gap;
    cards;
    10001      1        0        .
    10001      1        0        79  
    10001      1        0        48  
    10001      1        0        39  
    10001      1        0        74  
    10001      1        0        41  
    10001      0        1        21  
    10001      0        1        9   
    10001      0        0        130 
    10001      0        0        52  
    10001      0        0        110 
    10001      1        0        80  
    10001      0        1        29  
    10001      0        1        12  
    10001      0        1        23  
    10001      1        0        57  
    10001      0        1        28  
    10001      0        1        14  
    10001      1        0        118 
    10001      0        1        5   
    10001      0        1        22  
    10001      1        0        40  
    10001      0        1        23  
    10001      0        1        24  
    10001      0        1        19  
    ;
    run;

    data _null_;
    set have (keep=readmit) end=last;
    by readmit notsorted;
    if first.readmit then days=0;
    retain max_days;
    if readmit=1 then days+1;
        max_days=max(max_days,days);
    if last then call symput('max_days',strip(max_days));
    run;

    %put maximum consecutive days = &max_days.;

    data want;
    set have;
    by readmit notsorted;
    array dayvar{*} day1-day&max_days.;
        if first.readmit then do;
            num_day=0;
            call missing(of day:);
        end;
    retain day1-day&max_days.;
        if readmit=1 then do;
            num_day+1;
            dayvar{num_day}=gap;
            if last.readmit then output;
        end;
    keep studyid index day: ;
    run;
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. That's what I want. Super! Thank you for figuring out my unclear expression and thank you for your time.